# Проблема с установкой битрикса

Tags: битрикс

Во время установки битрикса выходит вот такая вот ошибка:

$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] variable must be set to the document root directory under which the current script is executing.
'; elseif (!file_exists($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/.access.php")) $strErrorMessage .= 'The file .access.php is not found in the site root. Apparently the installation package has been unpacked incorrectly.
'; if ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != "/index.php") $strErrorMessage .= 'Bitrix site manager must be installed in web server root directory.
'; if (!ini_get("short_open_tag")) $strErrorMessage .= 'short_open_tag value must be turned on in you php.ini or .htaccess file.
'; if (strlen($strErrorMessage) > 0) die(''.$strErrorMessage."
Please modify the server's configuration or contact administrator of your hosting."); define("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED", true); $success = include_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/main/install/wizard/wizard.php"); if (!$success) die('Folder /bitrix/ is inaccessible for writing and/or reading'); ?>

Подскажите как можно исправить эту проблему

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin готово

Answer (score 0):

Установка битрикс при использовании BitrixVM происходит с бубном - последнюю установку 2 дня переписывался с поддержкой, их ansible скрипты работают некорректно.
Ждать тут ответ дольше, чем связаться с поддержкой по вопросу установки нового сервера - там более развёрнуто ответят и в случае чего подключатся поправят.

Если по тексту - у вас точно корректно расположены файлы установки - стандарт /home/bitrix/www ?
Пользователю bitrix выданы полные права на данную директорию - согласно инструкций по установке с оф сайта битрикса? Ссылка на основную полную - https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=37&LESSON_ID=8811&LESSON_PATH=3908.8809.8811